# Swift 2 - kCTForegroundColorAttributeName

Tags: swift2, nsmutableattributedstring

```
let nameAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName:nameFont, kCTForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor] as [String:AnyObject]
var nameAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:name, attributes:nameAttributes)
```

I have these values which are working on Swift 1.2. But on Swift 2, they don't work.

I receive an error on first line:

> `'_' is not convertible to 'CFString'`

And the problem is `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName`. Without `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName`, it would works. But I need it to change the color..

In addition:

```
kCTForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7).CGColor
```

gives me an error:

> `'_' is not convertible to 'CGFloat'`

In Swift 2, attributes on `NSMutableAttributedString` has to be `[String:AnyObject]` while in Swift 1.2 was `[NSObject:AnyObject]`.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code

```
let attrs2 = [NSFontAttributeName : FontWithBook(10),NSForegroundColorAttributeName :UIColor.grayColor()]
var gString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"(Mandatory)", attributes:attrs2)
```